# Cant Set VCard In Asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

im trying to set a Simple NickName with my Beem-asmack to the openfire server like this :

```
 connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard",   
 "vcard-temp", new org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.VCardProvider());
            VCard card = new VCard();

            card.setNickName("NewNickname");
            try {
                card.save(connection);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the IQ packages are like this :

```
06-29 14:06:28.560: D/SMACK(2691): 02:06:28 PM SENT (-1274092112): <iq id="RJyL4-4"   
from="reza@reza-hp/Smack" type="set"><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'> 
<NICKNAME>NewNickname</NICKNAME>
06-29 14:06:28.560: D/SMACK(2691): </vCard>
06-29 14:06:28.560: D/SMACK(2691): </iq>
```

and response is:

```
 06-29 14:06:28.570: D/SMACK(2691): 02:06:28 PM RCV  (-1274092112): <iq type="result"  
 id="RJyL4-4" to="reza@reza-hp/Smack"/>
```

But my V-card is not getting updated. i havent seen a Vcard IQ before, but the response here looks empty , is there some thing else i should do? any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You did't load the Card.
Try this:

```
VCard vCard = new VCard();
card.load(connection);
card.setNickName("NewNickname");
try {
    card.save(connection);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```